# Google PageSpeed module on NGINX включить по запросу (не работает?)

Tags: nginx

Есть ли способ, чтобы включить pagespeed модуль в nginx с помощью запроса?

Я увидел, что в Apache, он может быть включен или отключен с помощью запроса. Например www.site.com/?PageSpeed=on

В конфиге Apache pagespeed должен быть установлен в "off". У Apache "off" значит "выключено, но можно включить по URL запросу".

Ок. Но в nginx "off" значит "выключен полностью" и по URL не включается. В Apache есть третий вариант для полного отключения модуля, а в NGINX знаю только две "off" и "on". Документацию google pagespeed читал но вопрос всё ещё остался.

Действительно что в nginx это не возможно?

Спасибо всем за ответы.

Comment: *У Apache "off" значит "выключено, но можно включить по URL запросу"* — а где вы об этом прочитали? насколько я вижу, в [документации](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration#module) такого, вроде бы, нет.

Comment: To disable HTML rewriting but continue to serve .pagespeed. resources and parse query options (for instance for ?ModPagespeed=on) put this line in your configuration:
ModPagespeed off

To completely disable mod_pagespeed (.pagespeed. resources will result in 404s) use the following line:
ModPagespeed unplugged

Comment: хм. да, у apache, действительно, три опции: on, off и unplugged. а у nginx-а только две. так что ответ на ваш вопрос: **нет, невозможно**.

Comment: Нет, это возможно. Ведь в документации для nginx это описывается. А здесь, разработчики решили что это баг. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ru#!topic/ngx-pagespeed-discuss/c2M80KOqUV0 Но предложенный ими workaround у меня например не сработал.